# Migration from SP 2013 to SPO date time issues

Tags: rest, datetime, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a SP 2013 that was migrated to SPO.

The problem is the Time Zone is Germany, migration take place in India, and I’m developing in Portugal.

So I have some dates 1 day head and others 1 behind consuming for on SPO Rest Api. But the dates are correct in the lists.

The source tenant is defined as 12H so as the target.

At this time I’m really confused, so kindly I’m asking for help on this.

Should I open a ticket? Someone had the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by

`moment(data).tz('Europe/Berlin').format('DD-MMMM-YYYY')`